Number of conjugacy classes of pairs of commuting elements II
This post follows up on a discussion initiated in Number of conjugacy classes of pairs of commuting elements.
Consider a finite group $G$ and let $r_G$ represent the number of conjugacy classes of pairs of elements that commute within $G$. This is, specifically, the size of the set $$ A_G = \{ c(a_1,a_2) \ | \ a_1,a_2 \in G \text{ and } a_1a_2 = a_2a_1\},$$ where $$c(a_1,a_2) = \{ (ga_1g^{-1},ga_2g^{-1}) \ | \ g \in G \}.$$
To understand the significance, it's worth noting that $r_G$ corresponds to the rank of the Drinfeld center of ${\rm Rep}(G)$. For further details, see this post.
Drawing from a comment in the preceding discussion, Dave Benson highlighted that the pairs of commuting elements $(g,g^n)$, for $0 \leq n < {\rm ord(g)}$, each fall into unique conjugacy classes. This implies that $r_G \geq {\rm ord(g)}$ for any $g$ in $G$. Specifically, by Cauchy's theorem, for every prime $p$ that divides $|G|$, we have $p \leq r_G$. However, a quick examination of small groups indicates that a better inequality should hold:
(Preliminary) Question 0: Is it true that for every prime $p$ dividing the order of any (non-trivial) finite group $G$, $p \leq r_G/2$?
The term "non-trivial" here is technically superfluous since $1$ lacks any prime factors. This question anticipates a positive response, based on an enhanced inequality suggested by Geoff Robinson in this comment, which improves on Benson's observation:
$$ r_{G} \geq |Z(G)|c_G + \sum_{g \in \Gamma_{G} \setminus Z(G) } {\rm ord(g)}.$$
The case of $G=C_2$ demonstrates the equality $p = r_G/2$, and the inequality $p \leq r_G/2$ holds for all finite groups with an order under $768$. However, for non-abelian groups, the expectations are higher:
Question 1: Is it correct that for every prime $p$ dividing the order of any non-abelian finite group $G$, $p \leq 3r_G/8$?
The equality $p = 3r_G/8$ holds for $G=S_3$, and the inequality $p \leq 3r_G/8$ appears valid for all non-abelian finite groups with an order under $768$. Yet, for non-solvable groups, an even better inequality is proposed:
Question 2: Is it true that for every prime $p$ dividing the order of any non-solvable finite group $G$, $p \leq 5r_G/22$?
Here, $G=A_5$ achieves the equality $p = 5r_G/22$, and this inequality is maintained across all non-solvable groups with an order under $1000$, as well as all non-abelian finite simple groups with an order under $10^7$.

Revised answer, to cover more of question: The proof that $r_{G} \geq \frac{8p}{3}$ if $G$ is non-Abelian is tedious, but not too difficult, I think, and this is attained, (as you say),for $p = 3$ by the symmetric group $S_{3}.$
Notice that we have $r_{G} > k(G)|Z(G)|$ if $G$ is non-Abelian, since $k(C_{G}(x)) \geq |Z(C_{G}(x))| > |Z(G)|$ whenever $x$ is a non-central element of $G$ (as usual, $k(G)$ for me is the same as your $c_{G}$).  Hence if $p$ divides $|Z(G)|$, then
$r_{G} > p(1+ |Z(G)|) > p^{2} + p \geq 3p.$ So we may suppose that $|Z(G)|$ is not divisible by $p$.
Then if $Z(G)$ has order divisible by a prime $q \neq p$, we have $|Z(C_{G}(x))| \geq pq$ whenever $x \in G$ has order $p$ or $pq$, so that $r_{G} \geq q(1+qp) \geq  4p+2.$
Suppose then that $Z(G) = 1.$ If $G$ has more than two conjugacy classes of elements of order divisible by $p$, we have $r_{G} \geq k(G)+3p \geq 3p+3,$ so we may suppose that $G$ has at most two conjugacy classes of elements of order divisible by $p$.
If $G$ contains an element $x$ of order $p$ whose centralizer contains an element of prime order $q \neq p,$ then all elements of $p$-power order (greater than one) are conjugate in $G$, and all elements of order $pq$ are conjugate in $G$. Hence all elements of order $q$ in $C_{G}(x)$ are conjugate. Then $G$ contains an element of order $p-1$ ( in $N_{G}(\langle x \rangle)$), and $C_{G}(x)$ contains an element of order $q-1$.
If $q \neq 2,$ then $G$ contains elements of order $p,q$ and ${\rm lcm}(p,(q-1))$, contrary to the above discussion, since we have at least three different conjugacy classes of elements of order divisible by $p$.
Hence we may suppose that $q =2$ and $p > 2.$ In that case we have $r_{G} \geq k(G) + pq + p + (p-1) > 3p.$
Now we may suppose that there is no such prime $q$, and that $C_{G}(x)$ is a $p$-group for each element $x$ of order $p$.
If $C_{G}(x)$ is non-cyclic for some non-identity $p$-element $x \in G$, then we have $k(C_{G}(x)) \geq p^{2},$ since the $p$-group $C_{G}(x)$ has an elementary Abelian homomorphic image of order $p^{2},$ so
$C_{G}(x)$ has at least $p^{2}$ irreducible characters, hence at least $p^{2}$ conjugacy classes. In that case, if there a non-identity element $y$ of $p$-power order in $G$ not conjugate to $x$, we obtain $r_{G} \geq k(G) + p^{2} +p > 3p.$ If there is no such $y$, then we still have $r_{G} \geq k(G) + k(C_{G}(x)) \geq 2 +p^{2} \geq 3p.$
Hence we may suppose that $C_{G}(x)$ is a cyclic $p$-group for each non-identity $p$-element $x \in G.$ If $G$ contains an element of order $p^{2},$ we obtain
$r_{G} \geq k(G) + p^{2} \geq 3 + p^{2} > 3p.$
Now we may suppose that $C_{G}(x)$ has order $p$ for each element $x \in G$ of order $p$. This forces the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ to be cyclic of order $p$.
If $p = 2,$ then $G$ has an Abelian normal $2$-complement $H$ of order at least $3$, and we obtain $k(G) = 2 + \frac{|H|-1}{2},$ while $C_{G}(h) = H$ for each $h \neq 1 \in H.$ This gives $r_{G} \geq 3 + \frac{|H|(|H|-1)}{2} + 2 \geq 8 = 4p.$
Suppose then that $p$ is odd. If $G$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup, then $G$ has order $\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$ or $p(p-1).$In the first case, $p >3$ (otherwise $G$ is Abelian) and $G$ has $\frac{p-1}{2} + 2$ conjugacy classes, so $r_{G} \geq \frac{p-1}{2} + 2 + 2 +2p + \frac{(p-1)(p-3)}{4} = \frac{p^{2}+6p+17}{4} > 3p$
since $p \geq 5.$
In the second case, $r_{G} \geq p + p + (p-2)(p-1) = 2+p(p-1) \geq 4p$ if $p > 3$. If $p = 3,$ we obtain $c_{G} \geq 8 = \frac{8p}{3}$.
Suppose then that $G$ does not have a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup. Then a Sylow normalizer of $G$ has order at least $\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$ and $G$ has at least $p+1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups, so $|G| \geq |{\rm PSL}(2,p)|.$
If $|N_{G}(P)| = \frac{p(p-1)}{2},$ and $p >3$, then we obtain $r_{G} \geq 2+ \frac{p-1}{2} + 2p + \frac{p-1}{2}> 3p$ because $G$ has two conjugacy classes of elements of order $p$ and (at least) one conjugacy class of elements of order $\frac{p-1}{2},$ while a theorem of Brauer tells us that $k(G) \geq 2 + \frac{p-1}{2}.$
If $p = 3$ and $N_{G}(P) = P$ for a Sylow $3$-subgroup $P$, then $G$ has a normal $3$-complement by Burnside's transfer theorem. By Thompson's theorem, this normal $3$-complement, $H$ say, is nilpotent. Let $M \leq H$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. Then $M$ is elementary Abelian and $M \leq Z(H).$
Now $M$ consists of $1 + \frac{|M|-1}{3}$ conjugacy classes of $G$, and for each $1 \neq x \in M,$ we see that $M \leq Z(C_{G}(x)),$ so we obtain
$r_{G} \geq k(G) + 6 +\frac{|M|(|M|-1)}{3}$ since $G$ contains two classes of elements of order $3$ . But we certainly have $k(G) > 3$ in this case, so $r_{G} \geq 10 > 3p.$
If remains to deal with the case $p > 3,$ $|N_{G}(P)| = p(p-1)$ and $N_{G}(P) \neq G$ for a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$. By a Theorem of Brauer, we have $k(G) \geq p$ in this case.
Hence we have $r_{G} \geq p + p + (p-1),$ since $G$ contains elements of order $p$ and of order $p-1.$
Now $3p-1 \geq \frac{8p}{3}$ for $p \geq 3$.
New edit: For the last part of the question, I can not prove the bound you would like, but I can prove the following: let $G$ be a finite group which is not solvable, and let $p$ be the largest prime divisor of $|G|.$ Then one of the following occurs:
$r_{G} \geq 5p-1,$ or else $G$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of order $p$ with $C_{G}(P) = p$ and $[N_{G}(P):C_{G}(P)] \geq \frac{p-1}{4}$ if $p >5$, while $[N_{G}(P):C_{G}(P)] \geq \frac{p-1}{2}$ if $p = 5.$
Suppose then that $G$ is not solvable, and $p$ is the largest prime divisor of $|G|$. Notice that $p \geq 5$ since $|G|$ has at least three different prime divisors by Burnside's $p^{a}q^{b}$-theorem.
Since $r_{G} = \sum_{x} k(C_{G}(x))$, where $x$ runs through a full set of representatives for the distinct conjugacy classes of $G$, we see that $r_{G} \geq |Z(G)|k(G) + 2(k(G)-|Z(G)|)|Z(G)|$, since $k(C_{G}(x)) \geq |Z(C_{G}(x))|  \geq 2|Z(G)|$ if $x \in G \backslash Z(G).$  In particular, $r_{G} \geq |Z(G)|(k(G) + 2).$
Also, we have $k(G) \geq 4$ since $G$ contains elements of order $1,p,q,r$ where $p,q,r$ are three of the prime divisors of $|G|.$ Thus $r_{G} \geq 6|Z(G)|.$
Hence  we are done if $p$ divides $|Z(G)|,$ so we may suppose that $Z(G)$ has order prime to $p$, and we do so.
We next claim that we are done if there is an element $x$ of order $p$ in $G$ such that $C_{G}(x)$ is a $p$-group, say $P$. For if $P$ is not cyclic, $then P$ has an elementary Abelian homomorphic image of order $p^{2},$ so (as in the earlier arguments), $P = C_{G}(x)$ has at least $p^{2}$ irreducible characters, and $k(C_{G}(x)) = k(P) \geq p^{2} \geq 5p.$ If $P$ is cyclic of order $p^{2}$ or more, then we again have $k(C_{G}(x)) \geq p^{2} \geq 5p.$ If $C_{G}(x) = P$ is cyclic of order $p,$ then let $S$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ containing $P$. Then $1 \neq Z(S) \leq C_{G}(x) = \langle x \rangle$, so $\langle x \rangle = Z(S),$ and then $S \leq C_{G}(x) = \langle x \rangle,$ so $P$ is a self-centralizing Sylow $p$-subgroup of order $p$ of $G$. We note also that, in any case, $G$ contains no element of order $p^{2},$ for if $y \in G$ has order $p^{2},$ then $k(C_{G}(y)) \geq |Z(C_{G}(y))| \geq p^{2} \geq 5p.$
Hence $G$ contains an element $x$ of order $p$ whose centralizer contains an element of prime order $q \neq p.$ We claim that all elements of order $p$ are now conjugate in $G$. Otherwise, $G$ contains an element $y$ of order $p$ in $G$ which is not conjugate to $x$, and we know now that $C_{G}(y)$ contains an element of order $pr$ for some prime $r$ different from $p$ ( though not necessarily different from $q$). These non-conjugate, non-central elements of respective order $p,pq,p,pr$ make a contribution of at least $6p$ to $r_{G},$ so we are done.
Now we claim that $q = 2$, and that $C_{G}(x)$ is a $\{2,p\}$-group with an elementary Abelian Sylow $2$-subgroup. We recall that $x$ is now certainly conjugate to all its non-identity powers, so that $G$ contains an element of order divisible by $p-1$ which is not central in in $G$ (and which lies in $N_{G}(\langle x \rangle)$). If $q \geq 3,$ we obtain a contribution to $r_{G}$ of at least $p + 3p + (p-1) = 5p-1,$ and we are done. Thus $q =2.$
Now if $G$ contains more than one conjugacy class of elements of order $2p$, then we obtain a contribution of at least $2p+2p + p =5p$ to $r_{G},$ and we are done. Hence all elements of order $2p$ in $G$ are conjugate.
Thus all elements of order $2$ in $C_{G}(x)$ are conjugate. Furthermore $C_{G}(x)$ contains no element of order $4$, since otherwise we obtain a contribution of at least $p + 2p + 4p \geq 7p$ to $r_{G}.$ It follows that $C_{G}(x)$ has an elementary Abelian Sylow $2$-subgroup $E$ whose non-identity elements are all conjugate within $C_{G}(x)$. By a theorem of Burnside, the non-identity elements of $E$ are ain fact all conjugate within $N_{G}(E) \cap C_{G}(x).$
Let $|E| = 2^{n}.$ Then $[N_{G}(E) \cap C_{G}(x):C_{G}(\langle x \rangle E)] = 2^{n}-1$ is also a power of $p$ since $C_{G}(x)$ is a $\{2,p\}$-group with a Sylow $p$-subgroup $E$.
Hence we either have $n = 1$, or else $p^{s}+1 = 2^{n}$ for some positive integer $s$.
In the former case, let $t$ be a generator of $E$. Then
$C_{G}(x) = \langle t \rangle \times P = C_{G}(x).$ Now we have $k(C_{G}(x)) \geq 2p$ and $k(C_{G}(tx) ) \leq 2p$, while $N_{G}(\langle x \rangle )$ contains an element of order divisible by $p-1$ which is not central in $G$ (and is different from $x,t$ or $xt$). This makes a contribution of at least $2p+2p+p-1 \geq 5p-1$ to $r_{G},$ so we are done.
Suppose then that $p^{s} +1 = 2^{n}$ for some positive integer $s$, and that $n > 1.$ Then $p^{s}+1 \geq 6 >4,$ so $p^{s}+1$ is divisible by $8$, and $s$ must be odd.
If $s > 1,$ then $\frac{p^{s}+1}{p+1}$ is an odd integer greater than one, but is also a power of $2$, a contradiction. Hence $s = 1$, $p$ is a Mersenne prime,
and $|E| = p+1.$
Now $E$ is not cyclic, and we know that all non-identity elements of $E$ are conjugate within $C_{G}(x).$ Set $U = O_{p}(C_{G}(x).$ Then $C_{G}(x) = UN_{C_{G}(x)}(E)$, so that $C_{E}(U) \lhd C_{G}(x).$ If $C_{E}(U) \neq 1,$ then we obtain $C_{E}(U) = E$ since all non-identity elements of $E$ are conjugate within $C_{G}(x).$ Then $E \lhd C_{G}(x)$ and $C_{G}(x)/E$ is a $p$-group (in fact, a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, since every element of order $p$ in $G$ is conjugate to $x$). If $C_{G}(x)/E$ does not have order $p$, then we may argue as before that $C_{G}(x)$ has at least $p^{2}$ irreducible characters, and we are done. Hence $C_{G}(x)/E = \langle x \rangle,$ so that $C_{G}(x) = \langle x \rangle \times E = C_{G}(xf)$ for each $f \in E.$ then $k(C_{G}(x)) \geq 4p$ and $k(C_{G}(xf)) \geq 4p$ whenever $1 \neq f \in E,$ so that $r_{G} \geq 8p,$ and we are done.
Hence we are left to consider the case that $C_{E}(U) = 1.$ Since all elements of $E$ are conjugate within $C_{G}(x),$ and since $U$ has odd order, it follows that all non-identity elements of $EU/U$ are conjugate within
$C_{G}(x)$, and we have $[C_{G}(x):U] = p(p+1).$
By the Hall-Higman theorem, we see that an element $w$ of order $p$ in $C_{G}(x)/U$ acts with minimum polynomial $(t-1)^{p}$ on $U/\Phi(U)$ (since such an element normalizes, but does not centralize the Abelian $p^{\prime}$-group $EU/U$. Hence $C_{G}(x)$ contains an element of order $p^{2},$ whereas we have seen that $G$ contains no element of order $p^{2}.$
Hence we are now in the case that $G$ has a self-centralizing Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of order $p$. If $G$ contains more than $4$ conjugacy classes of elements of order $p,$ then we have $r_{G} \geq 5p,$ and we are done. Otherwise, we have $[N_{G}(P):P] \geq \frac{p-1}{4}.$ If $p = 5,$ the inequality is strict, otherwise $G$ has a nilpotent normal $5$-complement, ( by Theorems of Burnside and Thompson), contrary to the fact that $G$ is not solvable.
We may go a little further. Let us consider the structure of the generalized Fitting subgroup $F^{\ast}(G).$ Suppose first that $G$ has a minimal normal subgroup $M$ of order divisible by $p.$ Since $G$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup of order $p,$ we see that $G/M$ has order prime to $p.$ Also, $M$ is not elementary Abelian, for otherwise $|M| = p$ and $C_{G}(M) = M$, so that $G/M$ is Abelian of order dividing $p-1$, contrary to the fact that $G$ is non-Abelian. Hence $M$ must be a direct product of various $G$-conjugate non-Abelian simple groups, each of order divisible by $p$. Since $p^{2}$ does not divide $|G|$, we see that $M$ is a non-Abelian simple group with $C_{G}(M) = 1.$ Now $G = MN_{G}(P)$ where $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$ of order $p$. Then $G/M \cong N_{G}(P)/N_{M}(P)$ and $N_{G}(P)$ has order dividing $p(p-1)$ since $C_{G}(P) = P.$
Hence $[G:M]$ is Abelian of order dividing $p-1$ (in fact $N_{M}(P) > P$ since $M$ does not have a normal $p$-complement, so that $[G:M] \leq \frac{p-1}{2}).$  Hence in this case $F^{ast}(G) = M$ is a non-Abelian simple group, and $G$ is an an almost simple group.
Suppose then that every minimal normal subgroup of $G$ has order prime to $p.$ Let $T = O_{p^{\prime}}(G)\neq 1.$ Then $P$ acts fixed point freely on $T$, so that $T$ is nilpotent by a Theorem of Thompson. Now we must have $T = O_{p^{\prime},p}(G),$ for otherwise we find that $PT/T \lhd G/T,$ and by an argument like that above, we see that $G/T$ is solvable of order dividing $p(p-1),$ in which case $G$ is solvable, contrary to assumption. Hence we see that $G/T$ is almost (non-Abelian) simple by arguments like those above. Now $C_{G}(T) \leq T$ since $C_{G}(P) = P,$ so $C_{G}(T) = Z(T).$ Then $T = F^{\ast}(G)$ in this case.
Hence we see that either $G$ is almost simple with $G/F^{\ast}(G)$ Abelian of order dividing $p-1$, or else $F^{\ast}(G)$ is a nilpotent $p^{\prime}$-group with $G/F^{\ast}(G)$ almost simple.

Indeed, you demonstrate that $r_G \geq 3p - 1 - \delta_{G, C_2}$ for any finite group $G$. Do you anticipate finding a non-solvable group $G$ where the inequality $r_G \geq 5p - 3$ does not hold?

Since I realise that $G = {\rm PSL}(2,7)$ also attains the bound $5p-3$ with $p = 7,$ I am inclined to think that it would be a delicate matter to actually prove the $5p-3$ bound in the non-solvable case.

Indeed, I've observed that as well. How does the presence of two examples that satisfy the equality $r_G = 5p-3$ complicate matters? In actuality, $G=A_5$ aligns with your second extra case, and $G={\rm PSL}(2,7)$ corresponds to your first extra case.

Well, if I look at ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$, I think you get $5p+3$ for $p = 11,$ so maybe there are several examples where the answer is around $5p$ for ${\rm PSL}(2,p).$ You need to find extra classes to make up for the bound from $p$-local information. Arithmetical accidents make up the deficit. Since what I did prove was not inductive, I am quite happy that I got the result as long as there is not a self-centralizing Sylow $p$-subgroup of order $p.$ But I think either a new insight or detailed knowledge of the structure of simple groups is needed to deal with the outstanding case.

@SebastienPalcoux : Here is another thought which someone may be able to exploit: if $x \in G$ is a $\pi$-group for some set of primes $\pi$, then the number of conjugacy classes of $C_{G}(x)$ is at least $|O_{\pi}(Z(C_{G}(x))|k_{\pi^{\prime}}(C_{G}(x)),$ where $k_{\pi^{\prime}}(C_{G}(x))$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $C_{G}(x)$ of elements whose order has no prime divisor in $\pi.$ This is bigger than $|Z(C_{G}(x))|$ when $C_{G}(x)$ has non-central $\pi^{\prime}$=elements. Easiest case to visualise is when $x$ is a $q$-element for some prime $q.$
